# ADB see physical device but Android Studio don't

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

My physical device is Huawei LUA-22, Android 5.1. And android studio don't see that phone, but ADB does. Usb debugging is enabled. Tried to change MTP to PTP and isn't work.

[image]

Comment: Most likely a Android Studio bug. I think this is not a question for StackOverflow

Comment: Please advise the site for such a question

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708&s=modified_time:descfirst

Comment: May be you have multiple adb versions installed? Make sure you only have the adb version from Android SDK installed and runing. Delete additional adb versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these steps(after unplugging the device).

1, Go to Sdk Manager and uninstall platform tools (Tools >SDK Manager>SDK Tools > Android SDK Platform Tools)
2. Restart Android Studio and install Platform tools again

should solve your problem but if it doesn't

3 Go to the Devices troubleshooter and start the troubleshooter again
4. Complete all the steps .

Also since it's an HUWAEI device make sure you have hisuite installed both on your phone and your laptop